# RoR 4.2: Find the view/template name from within a layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get the main view/template name from the layout, essentially so that I can target specific views with CSS without having to resort to `[data-action=new], [data-action=create], etc`.

Is there a way to do this without monkey patching `ActionView::TemplateRenderer` or similar, as that seems awfully heavy handed for something that should be quite simple.

Given that `controller_name` and `action_name` are readily available, I am failing to understand why there is no similar method for the view to be / being rendered.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using haml there's a nice helper method called `page_class` this adds the controller and actions as css classes, when added to the `<body>` you can target single pages with css
( if you're not using haml then i guess you could implement your own view helper to do this same funtion )

```
%body{ class: page_class }
```

The rendered view would be

```
<body class="my_controller my_action">
```

Then in the css you could use it to add conditions ( assuming you're targeting a div with id called `my_div` )

```css
#my_div {
  color: red;
  .my_action & {
     color: blue
  }
}
```

The output will become

```css
#my_div {
    color: red;
}
.my_action #my_div {
    color: blue;
}
```

This will make the color red in all pages, and blue only when the action is `my_action`

Comment: The controller and action names are already available via `controller_name` and `action_name` and are easy enough to add without a helper, but this doesn't solve the issue of an action rendering another action's view eg. the default resource new and create actions - the new action would get the classes `resources new` while the create action `resources create` meaning it will *not* get styles targeted at the new action. Yes, I could use `.resources.new, .resources.create` but a desire to *avoid* having to do that is kind of the point of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `request.fullpath` within the view. [See rails api](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/fullpath)

Comment: That gives the full path of the request, not the view / template. Consider the `new` and `create` - in both cases the view to be rendered is 'new' but using default rails resource routes the `request.fullpath` returns the following:

  new: `/resources/new`
  create: `/resources`